# What is the regexpression for fixed words and a variable

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using sublime to search and replace text in a code. 
This is what I want to find

```
pre + <anyvariable> + post
```

and then replace it like this

```
sanitize(<anyvariable>)
```

I don't know how to come up with regexp after finding  "pre + "

Came up with something like this

```
/(\pre \+)(?=.*)/g
```

Comment: You'll need to match the legal variable rules for your language. Unless there is going to be some other kind of stuff in between those two + signs you could probably just get away with what you already came up with.

Comment: So I came up with this Regex = `pre \+ (.*) \+ post` , and then replace  it like this `sanitize($1)`. However (.*) doesn't include break lines. still figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(.*\+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\+.*)$/
```

This will give you everything in three capture groups, starting from the beginning of the line between the first and second +, and then everything following to the end of the line. If there's other content such as more +'s, then this probably won't work blanketly.

Answer (score 0):

Without a computer, and not sure a out what you want, but if you search for:
pre \+ (.*?) \+ post

And replace with:
sanityze($1) (or \1 I never remember)

It should do what you want :-) 
If you want to be able to have linebreaks, replace .* by (?:.|\n)